# Método Genérico para Consulta REST

Tags: c#, .net, rest

preciso refatorar este método para que ele funcione melhor.

Este método funciona em perfeição quando a chamada em uma externa `API Rest` retorna lista. Porém, dá exceção quando o objeto de retorno da API externa Rest retorna um elemento apenas.

```
 public List<T> ChamarAPIListagem<T>(string chamada)
 {
     HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(chamada).Result;

     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
         var dados = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<T>>().Result;
         return dados.ToList();
     }

     return null;
 }
```

O Problema é quando a API retorna um objeto apenas. Ele dá erro de exceção:

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AppSpot.Ano]' because the
>   type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Embora não seja muito relevante, segue um exemplo do retorno em `JSON` da `API` externa;

Um exemplo de um retorno da API seria este:

```
[
    {"codigo": "320-1", "name": "Zer", "key": "320"},
    {"codigo": "201-1", "name": "201", "key": "201"},
    {"codigo": "201-1", "name": "201", "key": "201"},
    {"codigo": "201-1", "name": "201", "key": "201"},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse erro está dando porque está voltando apenas isso:

```
{"codigo": "320-1", "name": "Zer", "key": "320"}
```

No caso acima a API está voltando um objeto.

Para não dar o erro, o certo seria:

```
[{"codigo": "320-1", "name": "Zer", "key": "320"}]
```

Já neste caso acima a API está voltando uma coleção de objetos com apenas um item

Se você sabe quando a API irá voltar apenas o objeto, você pode criar um outro método que faz a leitura do objeto, exemplo

```
 public T ChamarAPI<T>(string chamada)
 {
     HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(chamada).Result;

     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
         var dados = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>().Result;
         return dados;
     }

     return null;
 }
```

E quando for uma coleção você chama o método da listagem.

**Dica**

Você não precisa passar o json para `IEnumerable<T>` para depois passar tudo para lista com o `.ToList()`;

Você pode diretamente ler como uma `List<T>`, ficando assim:

```
var dados = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<T>>().Result;
```